# Python venv module cannot add virtual environment name to PS1, when using PROMPT_COMMAND?

Tags: bash, python, git, prompt, virtualenv

I use the official Git Bash prompt support for displaying the current branch as part of the prompt.

My problem is that activating a Python virtual environment (`python -m venv <dir>`) using `source bin/activate` doesn't display the virtual environment name - `(atlassian-watchdog)` -  as part of the Bash prompt:

`nlykkei:~/projects/atlassian-watchdog (master *)$`

I've a strong feeling that it's failing, because I use `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `~/.bashrc` instead of `PS1`, but `GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS` works only with `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Is there any way to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` with Python virtual environments, so that the environment name gets added to the prompt, when it's active?

**~/.git-prompt.sh**:

```
# If you would like a colored hint about the current dirty state, set
# GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS to a nonempty value. The colors are based on
# the colored output of "git status -sb" and are available only when
# using __git_ps1 for PROMPT_COMMAND or precmd.
```

**bin/activate**:

```
if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1:-}"
    if [ "x(atlassian-watchdog) " != x ] ; then
       PS1="(atlassian-watchdog) ${PS1:-}"
    else
    if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
        # special case for Aspen magic directories
        # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
        PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
    fi
    fi
    export PS1
fi
```

**~/.bashrc**:

```
# git prompt
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u:\w" "\\\$ "'
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger - please see my solution.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to combine the relevant parts of `bin/activate` with `~/git-prompt.sh`.

Here `__git_ps1_venv()` is a function that wraps `__git_ps1()` and modifies the first argument of `__git_ps1()` to include the virtual environment.

The `PS1` variable should be set to the format of your prompt.

`~/.bashrc`:

```
##################
# Prompt
##################

__git_ps1_venv() {
   local pre="$1"
   local post="$2"

   if [ -n "${VIRTUAL_ENV}" ] && [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ]; then
      if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
         # special case for Aspen magic directories
         # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
         pre="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] ${pre}"
      else
         pre="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) ${pre}"
      fi
   fi

   __git_ps1 "${pre}" "${post}"
}

PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '

if [[ -r ~/.git-prompt.sh ]]; then
   . ~/.git-prompt.sh

   GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
   GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
   GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=1
   GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=1
   GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="verbose name"

   PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1_venv "'"${PS1%\\\$ }"'" "\\\$ "'
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, this should be the accepted answer, and this update should be merged into git's git-prompt.sh.